# Shell script to automate the checklist of the AWS environment

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, shell, automation

I have created an environment in AWS. The environment has networking (VPC), EC2 instances, RDS (MySQL), Redis, ALB, S3, etc.

Now I want to have a shell script (bash) that will show the

- EC2 instances - instance types, IPs, termination protection, etc.
- Networking - VPC and subnet CIDRs, DNS hostnames, DNS hostnames - enable or disable
- S3- Details like policy, bucket name, Default encryption, Default encryption, Replication rules, etc.
- RDS - ARN, end points, reader and writer instances, version, etc.
- Redis - version, node type, shards, total nodes, etc.
- ALB - DNS name, listeners, etc.

and need to have all these in a file as output.

Note: I have to give only the AWS account number, region, and tags as input.

FYI, the above input values have to be taken from JSON or any CSV file.

Can you please help me?

I tried some scripts, but they were not able to work properly.

Currently, I am manually updating and checking everything.

Note: **I have this environment that got created through Terraform that contains networking, bastion, the backend, a worker node, RDS, S3, and ALB. Now I want to validate these all as part of a checklist through automation. that I require in the form of a shell script with PASS or FAIL.**

Comment: This is a giant amount of information.  The aws cli is a good place to start but you've got a good amount of work ahead.  Start by automating the simple stuff and keep going.

Comment: You'll have to show us small, repeatable tests of your code that isn't working. Please  read, review and take to heart the items on this page : https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info . Skip the Version information at the top and search for the sections  labeled "Before asking about Problematic code" and "How to turn a bad script into a good question" .Good luck.

Comment: *" I am manually updating and checking everything.*". This is a good place to start.  Create a text file (look for option for Unix line endings), with `#!/bin/bash` as the first line, then copy/paste those commands into your file. Now you have a shell script!. You are probably hard-coding values for processing. Learn to replace them with `"$1"` (2,3,4....) and or `$*` or `"$@"`.  Read the tutorilal at https://grymoire.com/unix/Sh.html  . There is much good information at that site. Look arround. And yes, this will be some significant work. Good luck!

Comment: Do you have a _specific_ question or problem? What's working and what's not working?

Answer (score 1):

For these stuff IAC (Infrastructure As Code) tools such as Terraform are invented.
You can write down the specifics for your cloud resources (such as s3, lambda etc.) and can manage version, config, backend based on your environment settings.
Here are some [common aws services](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/AWS-IaCs-with-Terraform) written in terraform you can look as reference to start with terraform.

We use `terraform.env.tfvars` to pass environment specific variables. And [automate the whole thing using some bash scripts](https://github.com/ashraf-minhaj/Boring-Website). The reference repo is actually a project from which you can get ideas of how it's done.

Best wishes.

Comment: Hi, Ashraf Minhaj, Thanks for the update. I have an environment that got created through Terraform that contains networking, bastion, the backend, a worker node, RDS, S3, and ALB. Now I want to validate these all as part of a checklist through automation. that I require in the form of a shell script with PASS or FAIL.

Comment: By 'validate' what did you mean? Check if those resources are created? Or test them? Can you clarify that more?